# Deserializing a structure of classes into a list

Tags: json, title

I'm kinda new to JSON but managed to handle the concept for quite a while on # until I stumbled on this problem.
In the background, I receive a JSON string that I cannot change and of which I do not have the class definition. So I have to mimic them to deserialize first.

Basically, most of the time, I deserialize lists like

```
"table" : [
{object},
{object}
]
```

And I'm fine.
Though
I found this architecture in a corner of the string I receive:

```
"list" : {
"item1":{object},
"item2":{object},
"item2":{object},
...
}
```

And as this list is pretty big, I'm quite annoyed to have to reproduce the structure into a rigid class like:

```
public class itemClass
{}

public class list
{
public ItemClass item1;
public ItemClass item2;
public ItemClass item3;
...
}
```

My question is : Is there a way to interpret all the items as a list instead and use the tag they have in front as the value of an attribute ?
So basically, can I serialize an attribute so that it becomes the title of the seralized item and backwards ?

I could automatize and my life would get easier.

is there anything like:

```
public class ItemClass
{
[magic JSON attribute that transforms this attribute's value into the title of the serialized string]
public string title;
public int otherValues;
}

public class list
{
public List<ItemClass> items;
}
```

I hope you have some ideas to share.

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you are attempting to 'flatten' the list.  There are many different implementations of this function but they all involve using a programming language to parse and interpret the json first. Pick your language.

Comment: Ahhh ! Smart !
I'll do that, you are very right. Thanks for the tip !